# mapWithState assertion failed: Block rdd_45_0 is not locked for reading

Tags: scala, apache-spark, assertions

I'm using the function `mapWithState()` to count UV in my spark streaming application. After `mapWithState` I get a `dstream` and `foreachRDD` with it. In the function `foreachRDD`, there is a `rdd.foreachPartition` to foreach the Iterator, and next apply foreach on Iterator with Future, but I got an error in the Future.

- Error log here:

> ```
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0447 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 52.0 (TID 422). 1878 bytes result sent to driver
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0454 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: removing RDD 47
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0454 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 47
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0455 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Done removing RDD 47, response is 0
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0455 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Sent response: 0 to 192.168.1.30:43968
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0456 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: removing RDD 46
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0456 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 46
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0456 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Done removing RDD 46, response is 0
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0456 DEBUG BlockManagerSlaveEndpoint: Sent response: 0 to 192.168.1.30:43968
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0461 WARN BoneCP: Thread close connection monitoring has been enabled. This will negatively impact on your
> > performance. Only enable this option for debugging purposes!
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0873 WARN ClickAnalysis$: before parpair data with threadName=ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5 and threadId=46
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0873 WARN ClickAnalysis$: before parpair data with threadName=ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 and threadId=50
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0875 WARN ClickAnalysis$: come into foreach data with threadName=ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5 and threadId=46
> >     17/07/27 10:19:54.0875 WARN ClickAnalysis$: come into foreach data with threadName=ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3 and threadId=50
> >     Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:55)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$$resolveTry(Promise.scala:47)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:244)
> >         at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
> >         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
> >         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
> >         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
> >         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Block rdd_45_0 is not locked for reading
> >         at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
> >         at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.unlock(BlockInfoManager.scala:299)
> >         at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseLock(BlockManager.scala:720)
> >         at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(BlockManager.scala:516)
> >         at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator$$anon$1.completion(CompletionIterator.scala:46)
> >         at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:35)
> >         at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> >         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
> >         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
> >         at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
> >         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
> >         at ClickAnalysis$.doPrepairCamAndGmtUvPs(ClickAnalysis.scala:383)
> >         at ClickAnalysis$$anonfun$8.apply(ClickAnalysis.scala:353)
> >         at ClickAnalysis$$anonfun$8.apply(ClickAnalysis.scala:345)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
> >         at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
> >         ... 5 more
> ```

- and my code here:

  ```
  val mapState3=pairs.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunction).timeout(Duration(uvExpireTime.toLong))).map( x => (x._1, x._2.estimatedSize.toLong))

  mapState3.foreachRDD( { rdd =>{
  rdd.foreachPartition( uvRecord =>{
    if (!uvRecord.isEmpty) {

        doUpdateUV(uvRecord)

    }
  }) 
  def doUpdateUV(data:Iterator[(String, Long)]):Unit ={
      if(data != null){
      val f = Future{
      var connection:Connection = null
      try{
        connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection.getOrElse(null)
        connection.setAutoCommit(false)
        val camPs: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateUvCamCnt_sql)
        val gmtPs: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateUvGmtCnt_sql)
        logger.warn("before parpair data with threadName="+Thread.currentThread().getName+" and threadId="+Thread.currentThread().getId)
        for(uvRecord <- data) {
          logger.warn("come into foreach data with threadName=" + Thread.currentThread().getName + " and threadId=" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
        }
        logger.warn("come into batch update with threadName="+Thread.currentThread().getName+" and threadId="+Thread.currentThread().getId)
        camPs.executeBatch()
        gmtPs.executeBatch()
        connection.commit()
        camPs.close()
        gmtPs.close()
      } catch {
        case exception: Exception =>
          logger.error("Error in batchUpdate "+ exception.getMessage + "-----------------------" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception) + "-----------------------------")
          throw exception
      } finally {
        ConnectionPool.closeConnection(connection)
      }
      "success"
    }
    f onSuccess {
      case result => println(s"Success: $result")
    }

    f onFailure {
      case t => println(s"Exception: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(t)}")
    }
  }
  ```

I look forward for getting any useful solution for this problem .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Block rdd_xx_xx is not
> locked for reading

I fixed it by just adding more clusters. It seems to have been a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have read from the different jiras, this is a race condition. Multiple attempts at fixing it have been checked in. I am experiencing this issue in 2.4.4, and looks like 3.0.0 might have fixed this issue.

For me it is happening during a call to df.rdd.isEmpty()

If you want more information what I found here are the resources:

1. [First jira on the issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28009)
2. [Later jira on same issue (duplicate),
   but later spark version](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27666)
3. [More details on why this is a race
   condition](https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@spark.apache.org/msg229123.html)
4. [Very old jira when this seems to have first
   appeared](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18406)